# Animation when pressing "back" button on android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, back-stack

I am trying to create an animation when the user press "back" on his android device.
I would like to come back to the previous fragment and close the actual fragment by an animation from up to bottom to close the fragment.

Here is the code when i launch the fragment :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.animator.up_from_bottom);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And here is the code of R.animator.up_from_bottom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

And here is the exception :

```
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/InputEventSender(15279): Exception dispatching finished signal.
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: translate
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:129)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:126)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:93)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:72)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimator(FragmentManager.java:743)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1167)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:717)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1496)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:495)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2215)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2193)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2664)
03-19 22:20:38.498: E/MessageQueue-JNI(15279):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2423)
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the previous attribute: change the android:shareInterpolator to android:interpolator

Answer (score 1):

when using `setCustomAnimation` using standard `Fragment`s (as opposed to support library ones) you need to use `R.animator` instead of `R.anim`